# Convert specific SSE intrinsics to NEON intrinsics

Tags: c++, ios, sse, neon

```
> [EDIT: (edited to highlight the question in context)
```

Following are the SSE intrinsics for which *I require NEON intrinsics* as I am converting some SSE code to run on iOS.

- `_mm_set_ps`

Sets the four single-precision, floating-point values to the four inputs.

```
(__m128 _mm_set_ps(float z , float y , float x , float w );)

Return Value:
r0 := w
r1 := x
r2 := y
r3 := z
```

- `_mm_loadu_ps`

Loads four single-precision, floating-point values. The address does **not** need to be 16-byte aligned.

```
__m128 _mm_loadu_ps(float * p);

Return Value:
r0 := p[0]
r1 := p[1]
r2 := p[2]
r3 := p[3]
```

- `_mm_storeu_ps`

Stores four single-precision, floating-point values. The address does **not** need to be 16-byte aligned.

```
void _mm_storeu_ps(float *p, __m128 a);

Return Value:
p[0] := a0
p[1] := a1
p[2] := a2
p[3] := a3
```

- `_mm_add_epi32`

Adds the 4 **signed** or **unsigned** 32-bit integers in a to the 4 signed or unsigned 32-bit integers in b.

```
__m128i _mm_add_epi32 (__m128i a, __m128i b);

Return Value:
r0 := a0 + b0
r1 := a1 + b1
r2 := a2 + b2
r3 := a3 + b3
```

Note: Avoid unaligned memory access whenever possible. So, I need a way to convert unaligned access to aligned access (probably using padding).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not very familiar with NEON intrinsics, but I can name you the equivalent NEON instructions. You'll find the appropriate macro easily then.

_mm_set_ps

If the values are already in S registers, you just have to re-interpret them as D registers
Otherwise, you can fill a D register with a vmov instruction :
vmov.i32 d0, r0, r1

_mm_loadu_ps

vld1.32 q0, [r0]

_mm_storeu_ps

vst1.32 q0, [r0]

_mm_add_epi32

vadd.u32 q0, q1, q2

Comment: Hi, can you explain the vmov.i32? I cannot really find any meaningful documentation online?